# google maps API v3 doen't respond

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm new here.
I'm trying to make an application that calculates distance and driving time between two adresses using google maps API.

My problem is that google DirectionsService() doesn't seem to respond. and I can't figure it out. I have been trying to figure it out for one week now.

I hope you guys can help.
the problems seems to be in gmapApi.js

here is my code.
Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"           Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postbackObj() {
        var orig = document.getElementById('<%= txbOrigin.ClientID %>').value;
        var dist = document.getElementById('<%= txbDestination.ClientID %>').value;
        var temp = showLocation(orig, dist);
        __doPostBack('gmAPIObj',temp);
    }
</script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">< /script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gmapApi.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txbOrigin" Text="" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txbDestination" Text="" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="postbackObj()"/>    

<p>
    < asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPrint" />
</p>

</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

gmapApi.js

```
function showLocation(orig, dist) {
var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var t = "";
var request = {
    origin: orig,
    destination: dist,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};


directionService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        alert(status + "  \nreq. failed.");
    }
    else {
        t = request.origin + ';' + request.destination + ';' +  response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + ';' + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
    }
});

return t;
}
```

the response variable is null and the status variable is emptystring in the directionService.route(request, function (response, status)
I have tried to change  to  without lock. And I have tried to place the  tags in the body tag without lock.

the rendered html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postbackObj() {
        var orig = document.getElementById('txbOrigin').value;
        var dist = document.getElementById('txbDestination').value;
        var temp = showLocation(orig, dist);
        __doPostBack('gmAPIObj',temp);
    }
</script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gmapApi.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MjMyMzMwNTZkZHxi8IJlhy7bL8nAZqZfL2Vh4Yr8uF80ja6jX9Ypc87B" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"   value="/wEWBALsorucDwLTmobsAwK0weWLAwLCi9reA32PxME86E6mQhRTgBkF7cdktbiURIpf/IzKvAs5PHwI" />
</div>
<div>
<input name="txbOrigin" type="text" value="tilst" id="txbOrigin" />
<input name="txbDestination" type="text" value="aarhus" id="txbDestination" />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="postbackObj();" id="btnSubmit" />    

<p>
    <span id="lblPrint"></span>
</p>

</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

requesting the directionService is an asynchronous process, your variable t inside the function `showLocation` will not be modified by the call of `directionService.route()`

call `__doPostBack('gmAPIObj',t)` from within the successfull callback of `directionService.route()` instead.

---

```
function postbackObj() {
    var orig = document.getElementById('txbOrigin').value;
    var dist = document.getElementById('txbDestination').value;
    showLocation(orig, dist);
}

//-----

function showLocation(orig, dist) {
var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var t = "";
var request = {
    origin: orig,
    destination: dist,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};


directionService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        alert(status + "  \nreq. failed.");
    }
    else {
        t = request.origin + ';' + request.destination + ';' +  response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + ';' + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
       __doPostBack('gmAPIObj',t);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: hi Dr.Molle. I have changed the methos to       directionService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            alert(status + "  \nreq. failed.");
        }
        else {
            var t = request.origin + ';';
            t += request.destination + ';';
            t += response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + ';';
            t += response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
            __doPostBack('gmAPIObj', t);
        }
    });
but the problem is the same. the response is null :-(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that response cannot be null, because the status is OK, so response must be a valid directionsResult. I've also tested my suggestion and it works well. When the directionsService would'nt send any response, the callback of route() would never be executed.

Comment: now I have spent one week more on this project. I have tried your solution too but without lock. I have tried it on 3 servers and with chrome, IE9 and firfox 10. when I debug on these browsers, is the status = ""(empty string) and the response is "NOTHING", debuggers doesn't say that it is undefined nor it's null. I have tried this jacascript on a straight HTML page, and it works like a charm. I don't know what else todo. :-(

Comment: When you post a link to one of your unsuccessful attempts I may look what went wrong there.